# Identifying the Pixel format(Like RGB, CMYK, LAB..etc ) of image in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I have a set of images, I need to identify the image format.

When I try to do with the number of channels, there are multiple image format with the same number of channels
(For Ex: CMYK and YGBR have the same number of channels )

So this methodology didn't work for me.

Please help me, is there any methodology do differentiate the Image pixel format.

Comment: Do [`PIL.Image.mode`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.mode) and [Modes](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/concepts.html#concept-modes) help?

Comment: Are your images files on disk, like JPEG, PNG, TIFF? Or Numpy arrays in memory? If they are data structures in memory, how did you load them into memory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To determine the color scheme of image, use the following:

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open(PATH_TO_IMAGE)
img.mode
```

the field "mode" contains the data you need

It is written in more detail here:
https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.1.x/handbook/concepts.html